# How to write a simple program in c language to transform grams to miligrams and vice versa

Tags: c, data-conversion

I would like to write a program in c to convert miligrams to grams and vice versa. I have tried the approach below but i get zeros as an output. I wonder what is wrong.

my approach :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input;
    double mili = 0,gram = 0;

    printf("\n give input \n");
    scanf("%c", &input);
    if (input == 'g')
    {
        printf("\n enter grams to transform to miligrams \n");
        scanf("%f",&gram);
        mili=gram/1000;
        printf("\n the transformation of %.10lf grams to miligrams is %.10lf \n",input,mili);

    }
    else if (input == 'm')
    {
        printf("\n enter miligrams to transform to grams \n");
        scanf("%f",mili);
        gram=mili*1000;
        printf("\n the trasnformation of %.2f miligrams to grams is %.2f \n",input,gram);
    }  
    else
        printf("\n wrong input \n");

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: You are incorrectly printing `input` instead of `gram` or `mili`.

Comment: plus your math is wrong.. milligrams = grams * 1000 and grams = milligrams / 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues here:

First, for both `gram` and `mili`, you're using `%f`, which expects a `float *` when you're passing a `double *`.  You need to use `%lf` to read a `double`.

Second, you've got your calculations mixed up.  Milligrams = grams * 1000 and grams = milligrams / 1000.

Third, you're printing `input` in two places when you should be printing `gram` and `mili`.

Answer (score 2):

Your maths is mixed up as grams=milligrams/1000 and milligrams= grams*1000. You need to change the type of input to double instead of using float.

Comment: hmm apart from the math issue the most important thing is to get an output. The float ----> double declaration did the job thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To read `double` use `"%lf"`, reverse math for calculations, do not print `input` but `gram` and `mili`:

Corrected:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input;

    double mili = 0;
    double gram = 0;

    printf("\n give input \n");
    scanf("%c", &input);

    if (input == 'g')
    {
        printf("\n enter grams to transform to milligrams \n");

        scanf("%lf", &gram);
        mili = gram*1000.0;

        printf("\n the transformation of %lf grams to milligrams is %lf \n", gram, mili);

    }
    else if (input == 'm')
    {
        printf("\n enter milligrams to transform to grams \n");
        scanf("%lf", &mili);

        gram = mili/1000.0;

        printf("\n the transformation of %.2f milligrams to grams is %.2f \n",mili,gram);
    }
    else
        printf("\n wrong input \n");

    return 0 ;
}
```

Test:

```
 give input                                                                                                                                   
m                                                                                                                                             

 enter milligrams to transform to grams                                                                                                        
2000                                                                                                                                          

 the transformation of 2000.00 milligrams to grams is 2.00

 give input                                                                                                                                   
g                                                                                                                                             

 enter grams to transform to milligrams                                                                                                        
5                                                                                                                                             

 the transformation of 5.000000 grams to milligrams is 5000.000000
```

Comment: Solved! actually the problem was definatly the way i was trying to read the variable type as you all guys mentioned above. For double is %lf. What a silly mistake. The other issues with the mili and gram are solved. Thanks.

Comment: @OrestisLivas You are welcome! You may also consider choosing one of the answers and accept it. It helps people who helped you and you get points as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer